# jsoup getting the url from table td

Tags: java, jsoup

```
Element tables = doc.select("table")
Elements myTds = tables.select("td:eq(0)");
```

.....

```
thetext=td.text();
thehref=td.getElementsByTag("a[href]");
```

I am reading a table from a HTML page.
I want to read the

```
<td>
<a href="student-profiles/andy.html">Andy</a>
</td>
```

I want to read Andy and student-profiles.
thetext is printing Andy.
How can I get the href? I tried a couple of things but could not.

Comment: how about `thehref.attr("href")`

Answer (score 0):

//thehref=td.getElementsByTag("a");

```
function simpleURL(){
        var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        if(anchors != null & anchors.length > 0){
                thehref= anchors[1].href;  

        }       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. can I not do this thetext=td.text();
? i issue with what you suggested is that you are getting all the tags and than doing..mine is a very big page and I did couple of selects to reach there..also can I keep var anchors?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this:

Elements myTds = tables.select("td:eq(0)");
than on tds.attr(href);